# Getting value of text field in controller?

Tags: magento2, template, controllers

Magento 2.3

I added a new text field to review.phtml, it looks like that:

```
<input type="text" id="tel" name="pptel" />
```

Now in my controller I am trying to get that value, like this:

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('pptel');
```

Does not work, also $_POST and $_GET are empty. I guess the new field value is just not added to the request, but why? How would I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the url to the controller is correct or the data sent has the value of input?

Comment: I had it outside if the form ... put it inside the form and it works using getParam :-)